# Is it possible with backbone to create a route that match all urls beginning with something?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, url-routing

I'm trying to do a route with backbone.js that match '/object/:id'

Problem is, i can receive get parameters containing anything, including slashes, then backbone doesn't recognize this url : /object/1337?var=/hey

Can i ignore get parameters or simply say that i want my route to begin with '/object/:id?' ?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you URL encode the parameter?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally found a solution, maybe a little ugly

```
initialize : function() {
  this.route(/^object\/([^\?]*)\?/, "show", this.show);
}
```

Comment: That isn't that ugly, that's what [route](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#Router-route) is for and Backbone just translates the routing table to `route` calls internally anyway.

Answer (score 3):

I believe this would work for you:

'/object/:id/*splat'

Your 'id' parameter will still match your id and the 'splat' on the end will match anything that is appended at the end.  It will even match nothing.  So if you want to trigger this route without any get parameters then '/object/1337/' will work.  Notice the slash at the end.  It has to be there.

Your original link of /object/1337?var=/hey should also trigger this route.

EDIT:  You can read about splats at

http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#Router-routes

EDIT EDIT:  Your original link will work with the new slash in between your id and the '?'

/object/1337/?var=/hey

Comment: It matches, but the id is equal to 1337?var=/hey

Comment: Yup check my 'EDIT EDIT'.  You need the slash in between '1337/?' in order for all your get params to be wrapped up into the splat.

Comment: So no matter what.  Whether or not you have get params or not you will always have to append the '/' after your id.

Comment: Did you get a chance to try it out?

Comment: Not yet, i'll give it  try next time :)

Comment: Just checking up on this again if you tried it out or not.  I think it was what you needed, but if not let me know. :)

Comment: I used my solution since i prefer avoiding the trailing slash. But it would certainly work.

Answer (score 0):

I use following for this:

```
// Call for Backbone to make the route regexp
var route = Backbone.Router._routeToRegExp(route_string);
// Change the regexp to ignore GET parameters
route = new RegExp(route.source.replace(/\$/, "\\\/?(?:(\\\?.*$))*$");
// Create a route with a new regexp
// Backbone will not try to make a regexp from the route argument if it's already a RegExp object
this.route(route, name, callback);
```

Answer (score 0):

If all you want is to separate parameters from the fragment, I suggest using [backbone-query-params](https://github.com/jhudson8/backbone-query-parameters).

You can use common Backbone routes and the plugin will parse the GET parameters in an object that is then passed to the route handler function.

From the plugin's Github page:

```
routes: {
    'object/:id': 'myRoute'
}
...
myRoute: function(id, params) {

    // if the routed url is '/object/1337?var=/hey'
    console.log( id );     // ---> '1337'
    console.log( param );  // ---> { var : '/hey' }

}
```